# How to fetch array to object from many-to-many relationship

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm using PHP as backend and MySql database, I have this many-to-many relationship

```
Drivers{
id,
name
}

Units{
id,
name
}

Driver_Units{
id,
unitId,
driverId
}
```

When i run script get driver details by driver id, i want to have json response like this

```
{
firstName: driver_firstName,
lastName: driver_lastName
units: [unitObject1, unitObject2, unitObject...]
}
```

So i want to have driver object and array of his unit objects in one response.
I'm beginner at PHP and MySql and i would like someone good at it to help me with this script and tell me is my current script "good" and how i can fetch array of unit objects as part of this response and generally how i can improve this script.

**EDIT:**

I tried solution that i got as answer in this question and i have code like this

```
<?php
require_once '../../dbConnect.php';

$driver_id = '%';

if (isset($_GET['driver_id'])) {
    $driver_id = $_GET['driver_id'];
}

$driver_id = 3; //hardcode to test it

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("
    SELECT d.firstName, d.lastName, u.make, u.model FROM drivers AS d
    LEFT JOIN drivers_units AS du ON d.driver_id = du.driverId
    LEFT JOIN units AS u ON u.unit_id = du.unitId
    WHERE d.driver_id = ?");

if($stmt) {
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $driver_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($first_name, $last_name, $unit_make, $unit_model);
    $driver = null;
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        if (empty($driver)) { // On first row populate all the driver info
            $driver = array(
                'firstName' => $first_name,
                'lastName' => $last_name,
                'units' => array()
            );
        }
        if ($unit_name) {
            $driver['units'][] = array(
                'make' => $unit_make,
                'model' => $unit_model
            );
        }
    }

    $mysqli->close();
    echo $json_response = json_encode($driver); 
}

?>
```

But this code returns me a NULL, so it's like i don't get anything from this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the tables. And learn to use prepared queries to substitute user input.

I use `LEFT JOIN` so you'll get the driver information even if he has no units. The loop uses `if ($unit_name)` to skip the null unit information that `LEFT JOIN` returns in this case.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("
    SELECT d.first_name, d.last_name, d.otherAttribute, u.name, u.attr1 FROM Drivers AS d
    LEFT JOIN Driver_Units AS du ON d.id = du.driverId
    LEFT JOIN Units AS u ON u.id = du.unitId
    WHERE d.id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $driver_id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($first_name, $last_name, $driver_other, $unit_name, $unit_other);
$driver = null;
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    if (empty($driver)) { // On first row populate all the driver info
        $driver = array(
            'firstName' => $first_name,
            'lastName' => $last_name,
            'otherAttribututes' => $driver_other,
            'units' => array()
        );
    }
    if ($unit_name) {
        $driver['units'][] = array(
            'name' => $unit_name,
            'otherAttribute' => $unit_other
        );
    }
}
```

To get information about all drivers, use a 2-dimensional array where the first level is keyed off the driver ID.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("
    SELECT d.id, d.first_name, d.last_name, d.otherAttribute, u.name, u.attr1 FROM Drivers AS d
    LEFT JOIN Driver_Units AS du ON d.id = du.driverId
    LEFT JOIN Units AS u ON u.id = du.unitId");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($driver_id, $first_name, $last_name, $driver_other, $unit_name, $unit_other);
$drivers = array();
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    if (empty($drivers[$driver_id])) { // On first row populate all the driver info
        $drivers[$driver_id] = array(
            'firstName' => $first_name,
            'lastName' => $last_name,
            'otherAttribututes' => $driver_other,
            'units' => array()
        );
    }
    if ($unit_name) {
        $drivers[$driver_id]['units'][] = array(
            'name' => $unit_name,
            'otherAttribute' => $unit_other
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sending driver_id with ajax post method, i will try this out and check if it works good, thank you for quick answer.

Comment: If you're using POST method then it should be `$_POST['id']`, not `$_GET['id']`

Comment: Sorry i use ajax GET method since this is script to get driver and and his units.   I use POST for insert scripts.

Comment: Since im using $_GET['id'] to bind driver  id, do i need to make aditional change in script that you provided, probably bind params will need change ?

Comment: No, you don't need to make any changes. My code doesn't care how `$driver_id` was set, it just uses it.

Comment: Thx, your solution works good, you just have typo bind_params should be bind_param, and bind_results should be bind_result. Also one more question, can you tell me how i can apply same thing but i want to get ALL drivers and i want to fetch units inside every driver. So i need something like get all drivers and inside every driver i want units array, can you tell me how that code should look like ?

Comment: Take out the `WHERE` clause to get all drivers, and add `d.id` to the `SELECT` list. Then make the result be an associative array, where the driver ID is the index and the value is the information about the driver. Then `$driver` becomes `$drivers[$row['id']]`.

Comment: Can you please make that changes for me ?

Comment: I've added it, even though any competent programmer should have been able to make the substitutions as I described them.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
require_once '../../dbConnect.php';

$driver_id = '%';

if (isset($_GET['driver_id'])) {
    $driver_id = $_GET['driver_id'];
}

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("
    SELECT d.firstName, d.lastName, u.make, u.model FROM drivers AS d
    LEFT JOIN drivers_units AS du ON d.driver_id = du.driverId
    LEFT JOIN units AS u ON u.unit_id = du.unitId
    WHERE d.driver_id = ?");

if($stmt) {
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $driver_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($first_name, $last_name, $unit_make, $unit_model);
    $driver = null;
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        if (empty($driver)) { // On first row populate all the driver info
            $driver = array(
                'firstName' => $first_name,
                'lastName' => $last_name,
                'units' => array()
            );
        }
        if ($unit_make) {
            $driver['units'][] = array(
                'make' => $unit_make,
                'model' => $unit_model
            );
        }
    }
    $stmt->close();
    $mysqli->close();
    echo $json_response = json_encode($driver); 
}

?>
```

On this way i get driver details by driverId that i send over ajax request, and object looks like this:

```
{
firstName: John,
lastName: Doe
units:[unitObject1, unitObject2....]
}
```